# nuxt,js vue,js how to fetch data inside of table

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

i am new in vuetify and nuxt.js

i am getting data from database but i want to show that in vuetify table.

**Laravel API Controller**

```
public function businesslist() {
      $businesslist = Business::paginate(2)->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
      return response($businesslist);
    }
}
```

**MY Laravel API**

```
Route::get('/businesslist', 'BusinessController@userlist')->name('businesslist');
```

**MY Nuxt.js vue page**

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      Nutrition
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        append-icon="mdi-magnify"
        label="Search"
        single-line
        hide-details
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="businessuser"
      :search="search"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-card>
 </template>

 <script>
```

---

```
 export default {
        data() {
          return {
            search: '',
            headers: [{
                text: 'Name',
                value: 'name'
              },
              {
                text: 'Mobile  ',
                value: 'mobile_number'
              },
              {
                text: 'Location  ',
                value: 'location'
              },
              {
                text: 'Join Date  ',
                value: 'registration_date'
              },
              {
                text: 'Renewal Date  ',
                value: 'registration_renewal_date'
              },
            ],
            businessuser: [
    
            ],
          }
          },async asyncData({$axios}) {             let {data} = await $axios.$get('/businesslist')
                return {
                businesslist: data
                    }       },

      }
      }
       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [created](https://lavalite.org/blog/created-and-mountedin-vuejs#:%7E:text=created%20is%20called%20earlier%20in,export%20default%20%7B) event, in this event, call your **businesslist** API and in the response, you should assign received data to your **businessuser** vue js variable.
Let see here one example.

```
created () {
      this.initialize();
    },

 methods: {
   initialize () { 
    this.businessuser = businesslistApiCalling();    
   }
 }
```

businesslistApiCalling(); is just an example you should call here the API method to receive Json data from the Server.

Comment: thank you for reply can you post answer implementing my code

Comment: i am little bit unfused  so please help me

Comment: please help i am new in vue.js

Comment: export default {
        .....
  created () {
   this.initialize();
  },
  methods: {
     initialize () { 
   this.businessuser = businesslistApiCalling();    
     }
  }
      }, if my answer is helpful please upvote it.

Comment: its not working can you check my question one more time

Comment: @user12380208 What's not working? show me your API call.

Comment: created: function () {
        this.fetchData();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData: function () {
          axios.get('/Businessregisterlist').then(res => this.registerlist = res.data.registerlist)
        }
    }

Comment: @user12380208 Does it return Json data? please share Json response.